# How to apply an Affine Transform to an Android ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, matrix-multiplication, affinetransform

I need to reconstruct an image from a set of images.
Each image has an Affine transform that was calculated when the image was positioned at the center of view.

I made an example project with my implementation: https://github.com/tinytap/ImageViewMatrix.git

This is the right image result
[image: This is the right result]

This is the wrong result
[image]

Thanks for you help!

Comment: The Affine transform was made on IOS non-retina device,so in Android we need to calculate the scale between the specific device display and the IOS non-retina ratio. 
 These are the steps I'm doing:

1) Calculate the scale from non-retina to device display
2) Make a Matrix from the Affine transform values 
3) Translate Matrix from Top/Left to center
4) Scale Matrix by scale
5) Center images in center of screen
6) Apply Matrix to ImageView.